# What are the all possible tunable parameters of GridSearchCV? (for param_grid)

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, gridsearchcv

I have built an ANN with keras and I used GridSearchCV, in order to try different parameters and see which combination would give me the best result.

I'd like to know, whether all the parameters, which we define in the layers by Dense-module, are possible to grid in GridSearchCV? I am sure about the three parameters "batch_size", "epochs", & "optimizer". But I tried it for the activation function and after two days my computer didn't finish the grid search! So I stopped it and now I am looking for answers about this issue.

The code in the last lines is like below:

```py
def classifier_builder(optimizer):

    classifier = Sequential()
    classifier.add(Dense(units = 8, kernel_initializer = 'uniform',
    activation = 'relu', input_shape =(11,)))
    classifier.add(Dense(units = 8, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', 
    activation = 'relu'))
    classifier.add(Dense(units = 1, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', 
    activation = 'sigmoid'))
    classifier.compile(optimizer = optimizer,
    loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])  
    return classifier

classifier = KerasClassifier(build_fn = classifier_builder)
parameters = {"batch_size":[25, 32, 50],
              'epochs':[100, 500],
              'optimizer':['adam', 'rmsprop']}
grid_search = GridSearchCV(estimator = classifier,
                           param_grid = parameters,
                           scoring = 'accuracy',
                           cv = 10)
grid_search = grid_search.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

So my questios: Is it possible to give different activation functions & kernel initializers as I did above for batch_size & epochs? Or is it not a good idea to alter between various activation functions, because it changes the structure of the neural network each time? For example like this:

```py
def classifier_builder(optimizer,activ_func1,activ_func2):

    classifier = Sequential()
    classifier.add(Dense(units = 8, kernel_initializer = 'uniform',
    activation = activ_func1, input_shape =(11,)))
    classifier.add(Dense(units = 8, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', 
    activation = activ_func1))
    classifier.add(Dense(units = 1, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', 
    activation = activ_func2))
    classifier.compile(optimizer = optimizer,
    loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])  
    return classifier

classifier = KerasClassifier(build_fn = classifier_builder)
parameters = {"batch_size":[25, 32, 50],
              'epochs':[100, 500],
              'optimizer':['adam', 'rmsprop']
              'activ_func1':['relu','elu'],
              'activ_func2':['hard_sigmoid','sigmoid','softplus']}

#and the rest of the code is the same
```

Thanks a lot in advance :)

Comment: It would be better if you post this question on the following website: https://stats.stackexchange.com/, as the chances of you receiving good answers there are high

Comment: Check this link out: https://machinelearningmastery.com/grid-search-hyperparameters-deep-learning-models-python-keras/

Comment: Thanks a lot for giving this info :) I will do that certainly.